# Why am I given two reactances for a synchronous generator?

Tags: synchronous, alternator

I'm solving problems on the alternator and some of them give a reactance Xq in addition to the usual synchronous reactance Xd. Does anyone know what this Xq is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe q- and d- refer to machine rotor coordinate system axis (that are rotating with the rotor). This means the alternator has a different reactance in one than in the other direction (if it has **salient poles** obviously this has to be the case!).

See [this page](http://people.ece.umn.edu/users/riaz/animations/immodels.html) for further explaination of the dq coordinate system.